# Finding a Flash Content on web site

Tags: flash

I have a problem consider to Flash Player EOL - We have a site with a lot of flash content that need to be removed, but the site is so massive that it is hard to identify where .swf links are. Is there any opportunity to count how much unique references and where they are? Dr. Link check on exact URL shows only one link to .swf, even if there are several of them.

URL used for check: https://anthropologie.kunstkamera.ru/07/12online/klepikova_utehin?cut=1#2
[screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyyuP.png)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I guess you could start by counting the number of <object> elements on the page using your browser's dev tools or something.

Comment: _"We have a site..."_ Why not make a Javascript code that loads the text of html files into String objects? Then use String functions like `indexOf` and `subString` to exract SWF links? Basically you want to find every `.swf` text and scan backwards up to first instance of `http` text, which would be the start of the SWF link and extract that into some list.

Comment: @VC.One I really don't think they're asking how to do it in ActionScript.

Comment: @Organis I meant String functions of Javascript. They have a site so they have some access to Javascript knowledge. From there it's just a matter of doing an `XMLHttpRequest` to load the `.html`file(s) as text and a JS function to extract the URLs of the SWF files (as I described above). Finally export (write) the collected "Flash Links"  as a text file.